OpenCV SSD MobileNet V2 Model: No Object Detection Despite Confidence Threshold
I'm using a Basler camera with OpenCV's DNN module to run an SSD object detection model (mobilenetv2_050_Opset18.onnx) with CUDA support enabled on c++. The Basler camera is correctly capturing frames, and OpenCV is processing the images, but the SSD model doesn't detect any objects, not even with a confidence threshold as low as 0.0001.
Key Details:
Camera: Basler camera is configured for 640x480 resolution and BGR8 pixel format.
Model: SSD model (mobilenetv2_050_Opset18.onnx) loaded using OpenCV DNN module with CUDA backend (DNN_BACKEND_CUDA).
CUDA Support: OpenCV compiled with CUDA and cuDNN support with cmake. The backend is set to use CUDA (net.setPreferableBackend(DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)), and the target is also set to CUDA (net.setPreferableTarget(DNN_TARGET_CUDA)).
Problem: The model is not detecting any objects, even with a confidence threshold as low as 0.0001. I have verified that both the camera and the CUDA environment are functioning as expected.
What is the problem in my code?
#include <iostream>
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/InstantCamera.h>
#include <pylon/BaslerUniversalInstantCamera.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>

using namespace Pylon;
using namespace GenApi;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;

int main() {
    PylonInitialize();
    
    try {
        // Basler camera setup
        CInstantCamera camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateDevice(CDeviceInfo().SetSerialNumber("40432296")));
        camera.Open();

        // Configure the camera settings
        INodeMap& nodemap = camera.GetNodeMap();
        CIntegerParameter width(nodemap, "Width");
        CIntegerParameter height(nodemap, "Height");
        CEnumParameter pixelFormat(nodemap, "PixelFormat");
        CFloatParameter exposureTime(nodemap, "ExposureTime");
        CFloatParameter acquisitionFrameRate(nodemap, "AcquisitionFrameRate");
        CIntegerParameter xOffset(nodemap, "OffsetX");
        CIntegerParameter yOffset(nodemap, "OffsetY");

        width.SetValue(640, IntegerValueCorrection_Nearest);
        height.SetValue(480, IntegerValueCorrection_Nearest);
        pixelFormat.SetValue("BGR8");
        exposureTime.SetValue(15000.0);
        acquisitionFrameRate.SetValue(5000.0);
        xOffset.SetValue(0);
        yOffset.SetValue(0);

        CGrabResultPtr grabResult;

        // Load SSD model
        Net net = readNetFromONNX("mobilenetv2_050_Opset18.onnx");
        net.setPreferableBackend(DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
        net.setPreferableTarget(DNN_TARGET_CUDA);

        camera.StartGrabbing();
        Mat frame;
        while (camera.IsGrabbing()) {
            camera.RetrieveResult(5000, grabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);
            if (grabResult->GrabSucceeded()) {
                uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*)grabResult->GetBuffer();
                frame = Mat(grabResult->GetHeight(), grabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, buffer);

                // Run SSD model
                Mat blob = blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, Size(640, 480), Scalar(), true, false);
                net.setInput(blob);

                Mat detections = net.forward();

                for (int i = 0; i < detections.size[2]; ++i) {
                    float confidence = detections.ptr<float>(0)[i * 7 + 2]; // Access confidence

                    if (confidence > 0.0001) {
                        int xLeftBottom = static_cast<int>(detections.ptr<float>(0)[i * 7 + 3] * frame.cols);
                        int yLeftBottom = static_cast<int>(detections.ptr<float>(0)[i * 7 + 4] * frame.rows);
                        int xRightTop = static_cast<int>(detections.ptr<float>(0)[i * 7 + 5] * frame.cols);
                        int yRightTop = static_cast<int>(detections.ptr<float>(0)[i * 7 + 6] * frame.rows);

                        rectangle(frame, Point(xLeftBottom, yLeftBottom), Point(xRightTop, yRightTop), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                    }
                }

                imshow("SSD Detection", frame);
                if (waitKey(1) == 27) break; // Press 'ESC' to exit
            }
        }

        camera.Close();
    }
    catch (const GenericException& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.GetDescription() << std::endl;
    }

    PylonTerminate();
    return 0;
}

I am new to Computer Vision and I am aiming for a high performance(100+ fps) real-time object detection model to work with low res footage like 640x480 etc. Is OpenCv good starting point or should I skip C++ and use Python for better support etc. Is using C++ advantageous over Python when it comes to Object Detection model performance?

Instead of
blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, Size(640, 480), Scalar(), true, false);

Try
Mat blob = blobFromImage(frame, 1/127.5, Size(300, 300), Scalar(127.5, 127.5, 127.5), true, false);
net.setInput(blob);
Mat detections = net.forward();

